# compare clusters' objects in R

Tags: r, list, comparison, cluster-analysis

I have two clustering results for the same variables but with different values each time. Let us create them with the following code:

```
set.seed(11)
a<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)
colnames(a)<-(c(1:100))
set.seed(31)
b<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)
colnames(b)<-colnames(a)
c.a<-hclust(dist(t(a)))
c.b<-hclust(dist(t(b)))
# clusters
groups.a<-cutree(c.a, k=15)
# take groups names
clus.a=list()
for (i in 1:15) clus.a[[i]] <- colnames(a)[groups.a==i]
# see the clusters 
clus.a
groups.b<-cutree(c.b, k=15)
clus.b=list()
for (i in 1:15) clus.b[[i]] <- colnames(b)[groups.b==i]
# see the clusters
clus.b
```

What I get from that is two lists, `clus.a` and `clus.b` with the names (here just numbers from 1 to 100) of each cluster's variables.

Is there any way to examine if and which of the variables are clustered together in both clusterings? Meaning, how can I see if I have variables (could be teams of 2, 3, 4 etc) in same clusters for both `clus.a` and `clus.b` (doesn't have to be in the same cluster number).

Comment: In your example, are there any sets of variables in `a` which cluster together identically in `b`?? I don't think so.

Comment: No, but it was just a random one. So in this case I should had an output indicating that there are no 2 or more variables clustered together in both clusterings

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if there are any clusters in `a` which have exactly the same membership as any of the clusters in `b`. Here's one way to do that.

Note: AFAICT in your example there are no matching clusters in `a` and `b`, so we create a few artificially to demo the solution.

```
# create artificial matches
clus.b[[3]]  <- clus.a[[2]]
clus.b[[10]] <- clus.a[[8]]
clus.b[[15]] <- clus.a[[11]]

f <- function(a,b) (length(a)==length(b) & length(intersect(a,b))==length(a))
result <- sapply(clus.b,function(x)sapply(clus.a,f,b=x))
which(result, arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   2   3
# [2,]   8  10
# [3,]  11  15
```

So this loops through all the clusters in `b` (`sapply(clus.b,...)`) and for each, loops through all the clusters in `a` looking for an exact match (in arbitrary order). For there to be a match, both clusters must have the same length, and the intersection of the two must contain all the elements in either - hence have the same length. This process produces a logical matrix with rows representing `a` and columns representing `b`.

*Edit*: To reflect the fact that OP is changing the question.

To detect clusters with two or more common elements, use:

```
f <- function(a,b) length(intersect(a,b))>1
result <- sapply(clus.b,function(x)sapply(clus.a,f,b=x))
matched <- which(result, arr.ind=TRUE)
matched
#       row col
#  [1,]   4   1
#  [2,]   8   1
#  [3,]  11   1
#  [4,]   3   2
#  ...
```

To identify which elements were  present in both:

```
apply(matched,1,function(r) intersect(clus.a[[r[1]]],clus.b[[r[2]]]))
```

Comment: Thanks. To make my self clear, I want to see if there are **any** groups of 2 or more variables that are clustered together in both clusterings. Let's say I have in `clus.b[[2]]` the variables `11,14,22,40` and in `clus.a[[3]]` the variables `45,12,11,14`. I want to detect that Var.11 and 14 are clustered together in both clustering **regardless** other memeberships.

Comment: This is *not* what you asked. So do you want to know if such clusters exist, or which variables are in common??

Comment: This is exactly what I asked :-) What I want is in the question. I quote: how can I see if I have variables (could be teams of 2, 3, 4 etc) in same clusters for both clus.a and clus.b (doesn't have to be in the same cluster number). Can't describe it more clear, even with the example here in the comment. Thanks anyhow for your time.

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Comment: Partly yes, I need to add something to detect which are there variables but it's easy. Also I don't see how the fact that you misunderstood what I want to find translates on: the OP changing the question.. My question was there from the beginning, unedited and never actually changed. I just tried to explain it more with an example.